# How to show/hide Profile GPU rendering as bars using adb command?

Tags: android, adb, dumpsys

I'm trying to automate some of the tasks which I do while development on a regular basis using scripts. One of which is switching on and off GPU Profile rendering. However, I can't find the adb command to show/hide it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **Profile GPU Rendering** checkbox in the **Developer Options** controls value of the `debug.hwui.profile` system property:

```
/**
  * System property used to enable or disable hardware rendering profiling.
  * The default value of this property is assumed to be false.
  *
  * When profiling is enabled, the adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo command will
  * output extra information about the time taken to execute by the last
  * frames.
  *
  * Possible values:
  * "true", to enable profiling
  * "visual_bars", to enable profiling and visualize the results on screen
  * "false", to disable profiling
  *
  * @see #PROFILE_PROPERTY_VISUALIZE_BARS
  *
  * @hide
  */
public static final String PROFILE_PROPERTY = "debug.hwui.profile";
```

So you can use `setprop debug.hwui.profile visual_bars` command to enable profiling and `setprop debug.hwui.profile false` to disable it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @alex-p.

Comment: Do you know how to enable "debug GPU overdraw" via adb too? I'm talking about this: https://developer.android.com/studio/images/profile/gpu/gpu-overdraw-before_2x.png . I've found that in order to enable it, I can use "./adb shell setprop debug.hwui.overdraw show` , but how can I hide it?